# Distinguish whether helper is called with or without a hash (#)

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I need to distinguish how the helper is being called, for example following 2 cases

```
{{#myHelper data}}{{myHelperResponse}}{{/myHelper}}

{{myHelper data}}
```

Within the Javascript helper method, is it possible to distinguish between these 2 calls.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the last argument `options`. When calling an helper method with opening and closing mustaches, there are 2 methods available `options.fn` and `options.inverse`, such as:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('myHelper', function() {
  const options = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
  return options.fn ? options.fn('TRUE') : 'FALSE';
});

{{#myHelper}}{{this}}{{/myHelper}} // This outputs TRUE

{{myHelper}} // This outputs FALSE
```